# View is passing a different id to the controller and gets me the error Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a table "Crop" and a table "Harvest", and when I try to save a harvest, the controller is getting the previous crop_id, for example, if I'm harvesting from crop_id = 2 the controller saves crop_id = 1, and if I save crop_id = 1 the controller saves crop_id = 0 and throws the error.
Here are my models:
Harvest:

```
    class Harvest extends Model
{
    protected $table = "harvest";

    protected $fillable = ['users_id', 'farms_id', 'crops_id', 'totalProduction'];
[...]   

    public function crop(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Crop');
    }    
}
```

Crop:

```
class Crop extends Model
{
    protected $table = "crops";

    protected $fillable = ['users_id', 'farms_id', 'product_id'];    
    [...]
    public function harvest(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Harvest');
    }
}
```

HarvestController:

```
class HarvestController extends Controller
{
[...]
public function create()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $farms = Farm::where('users_id', Auth::id())->with('alias')->pluck('alias', 'id');
        $crops = Crop::where('users_id', Auth::id())->with('id')->pluck('id');
        return view('harvest.create')
        ->with('farms', $farms)
        ->with('crops', $crops);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $harvest = new Harvest($request->all());
        $harvest->users_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $harvest->save();

        return redirect()->route('harvest.index');
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('crops_id', 'Crop ID') !!}
            {!! Form::select('crops_id', $crops, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
        </div>
```

The dd() command on store() returns this:

```
"farms_id" => "1"
    "crops_id" => "0"    
    "users_id" => 1
```

FYI, I don't need totalProduction to create a record, it can be added later, and I know im repeating users_id on both tables, but lets just focus on the crops hehe

Comment: You probably need to phrase your questions a little better, for instance, you haven't said where you are doing the dd() function. Also remove things that aren't relevant to the question, such as totalProduction. What do you get with your $request->all() in the store() function of the controller?

Comment: @Jason sorry I skipped that, I've edited the question. Actually, what I found in the source code of the page is that the page is retrieving the wrong ID's in the first place. As you can see on the controller, I do the exact same thing with farms, and it works perfectly, passing correct ID's to the page. Don't know what I'm doing wrong with the pluck on the controller maybe? Any help will be aprecciated

Comment: I think the problem is that `pluck` is using a `0 indexed array`. The index is being used as the value, so `0 => 1, 1 => 2`, so your select options are looking like: `<option value="0"> 1 </option>` and `<option value="1"> 2 </option>`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy actually that is the problem, thanks a lot m'dude

Comment: also `$this->middleware` in any method besides the constructor isn't going to help.

Comment: @lagbox I'm listening...or reading...go on please

Comment: the middleware has already been collected and ran by the time the request is dispatched to the controller method. You are just calling that middleware method for no reason at that point, it does nothing.